# Polars counting elements in list column

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I've have dataframe with column **b** with list elements, I need to create column **c** that counts number elements in list for every row. Here is toy example in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[[1,2,3], [2], [5,0]]})

    a   b
0   1   [1, 2, 3]
1   2   [2]
2   3   [5, 0]

df.assign(c=df['b'].str.len())

    a   b           c
0   1   [1, 2, 3]   3
1   2   [2]         1
2   3   [5, 0]      2
```

Here is my equivalent in Polars:

```
import polars as pl

dfp = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[[1,2,3], [2], [5,0]]})

dfp.with_columns(pl.col('b').apply(lambda x: len(x)).alias('c'))
```

I've a feeling that `.apply(lambda x: len(x))` is not optimal.

Is a better way to do it in Polars?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [.list.len()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.len.html#polars.Expr.list.len)

```
df.with_columns(c = pl.col("b").list.len())
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b         ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ [2]       ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ [5, 0]    ┆ 2   │
└─────┴───────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: - Just a minor update - `list.lengths` has been updated to `list.len` in the latest versions of the library.

Answer (score 2):

Since polars 0.18.0 `arr` has been renamed to `list`. A working solution now is thus (taken from the above example):

```
df.with_column(pl.col("b").list.lengths().alias("c"))
```